# Can't iterate over ListView Items in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I write this code:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();

foreach (ListViewDataItem item in lv.Items)
{

}
```

I get "**the type or name ListViewDataItem could not be found**"

**Items** is also not found under the lv object.

Basically I need to iterate through each row of the ListView and set a checkbox added using item template.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You're creating a new ListView but not filled with items, so you can't iterate through an empty list.

Comment: This sample is just for simplicity but my real ListView has 2 items

Comment: did you try foreach (var item in lv) { } ?

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type listview

Comment: C# 'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

Comment: Actually, the property you're looking for should be `ItemsSource`, isn't it?

Comment: Some notes:

 1. The `ListView` is a `VisualElement`;
 2. There's no property `Items` indeed, the list elements are inside the `ItemsSource` property;
 3. Again, it's elements are `VisualElement`s eighter.

Comment: LIstView is a databound control, so if you want to iterate over its content and modify them, you should do this on the bound ItemsSource, not on the ListView control itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to loop through a listview is to access it's ItemsSource.  Then you can cast the item into your view model and do stuff with it.

```
foreach (var item in lv.ItemsSource)
{
    // cast the item 
    var dataItem = (ListViewDataItem) item;

    // then do stuff with your casted item
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems ListViewDataItem does not exist in Xamarin Forms: C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It depends on what class (view model) you are using to create your items for your listview.  I was assuming the class is `ListViewDataItem` in your code.

It will be useful if you can provide all the code that are related to your listview

Comment: @joseluisgonzalezclua I thought ListViewDataItem would be a custom class you wrote

Comment: This is the bigger picture: I need to create a list view with checkboxes inside each row and this should be a unique selection checkbox so that the user can only select one in the lilst view. I was trying to iterate in the list to set the checkboxes to true or false, one by one.

Comment: Maybe it's better to include your current attempts of putting check boxes in the ListView (your code) so it reflects your actual intention of your question

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop to iterate over my listView ChildCount, assigned a var as the Tag of the GetChildAt as ImageAdapterViewHolder and then set my checkbox to false.

```
class ImageAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public ImageView SavedImage { get; set; }
    public TextView Description { get; set; }
    public CheckBox SelectImage { get; set; }

}

for (int i = 0; i < listView.ChildCount; i++)
{
    var row = listView.GetChildAt(i).Tag as ImageAdapterViewHolder;
    row.SelectImage.Checked = false;
}
```